# Block notifications by default is Firefox

Tags: firefox

`dom.webnotifications.enabled` option disables notifications completely, which is not what is needed. Is it possible to just have notifications blocked for all websites unless I manually press bubble in adress bar and turn them on? Maybe there's a way to do it via injecting some JS into browser itself somehow?

Comment: [At the bottom of this Mozilla answer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1139372#answer-947512) it says websites can create the dialog even if all related services are disabled.

Comment: @Jason I believe they are just talking about a page element designed to look like a permission popup. That's how I understand "pre-permission dialog".

Comment: Isn't that what you're asking to disable, the permission dialog?

Comment: @Jason Obviously, nothing can stop the programmer from doing whatever they like with their page, including emulating permission dialogs. So no, I am only asking about the native dialog: whether it is possible to have it as if I've already clicked "Never allow" for all the sites.